# Replace " with \", only if enclosed by "

Tags: php, regex

I'm reading a string from my database for which json_encode doesn't work. (Using PHP)

I need to replace all occurrences of `"` with `\"`, but only if the occurrence is already enclosed by `"`.

Sample string:

```
{"val1": "This is "some value" that is inside of the "string" and such", "val2": "And here is yet another "value" that is messed up by quotation marks", "val3": "etc. etc."}
```

Should be changed into:

```
{"val1": "This is \"some value\" that is inside of the \"string\" and such", "val2": "And here is yet another \"value\" that is messed up by quotation marks", "val3": "etc. etc."}
```

Comment: lol, how you gonna know when you hit a closing `"`?

Comment: exactly how does json_encode "not work"? There's no way json_encode would produce invalid json. It either succeeds, or it returns a boolean false. it doesn't return an invalid json string.

Comment: Fix your database insertion code or get rid of the manual JSON construction thing. You're not going to be able to undo the damage reliably. (Btw, have you tried anything?)

Comment: I agree with mario, you need to fix the root cause of the problem.  Just out of curiosity, what happens if you encapsulate the string with single quotes?

Comment: json_encode escapes all occurences of ". When using single quotes it works - so for now I'll just avoid double quotes untill I can fix the insertion as suggested.

Comment: by the way it could be NOT the wrong database data :-) may be there is some  transformation of real data after extracting from sql response :-)  so could @Publicus please show us the php code that recieve/extracting  this string from database?

Comment: A closing `"` should be followed by a `,` or `}`, while the opening `"` would be preceded by a colon `:` and space.

Comment: This is undecidable problem. When you have `{"val1": "a", "val2": "b", "val3": "c"}`, it might mean `{"val1": "a\", \"val2\": \"b", "val3": "c"}` or `{"val1": "a", "val2": "b\", \"val3\": "c"}` or maybe `{"val1": "a", "val2\": \"b\", \"val3": "c"}` or maybe something different. So, fix the encoding, if possible. If not, you are in a serious trouble.

Comment: By the way, it is also important to escape `\` to `\\`. Without it, `\"` is escaped just to `\\"`, which is a `\` character followed by end-of-string,

Comment: Ignore my prior comment, I think matching the *values* inside the double quotes can be done as follows, *but only if there are no commas or colons or curly braces in the text*: `(?<=\")(.+?)(?=\"[,}:])`. You could then loop over these matches and replace any double quote characters `"` in them with `\"`. See regex demo here: https://regex101.com/r/eH4gS3/1

Answer (score 0):

**Try this instruction:**

At first replace `"` with `\"`

And replace again by regex following way:

```
$a='{"val1": "This is "some value" that is inside of the "string" and such", "val2": "And here is yet another "value" that is messed up by quotation marks", "val3": "etc. etc."}';
var_dump($a);
$a=str_replace('"','\"',$a);
var_dump($a);
$re = "~(\\\\\")([^\":]+)(\\\\\"):\\s*(\\\\\")([^,]+)(\\\\\")([,}])~m"; 
$str =$a;
$subst = "\"$2\": \"$5\"$7"; 
$a=preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
var_dump($a);
```

[live demo](https://regex101.com/r/fL3vB5/2)

**Output:**

```
string '{"val1": "This is "some value" that is inside of the "string" and such", "val2": "And here is yet another "value" that is messed up by quotation marks", "val3": "etc. etc."}' (length=173)

string '{\"val1\": \"This is \"some value\" that is inside of the \"string\" and such\", \"val2\": \"And here is yet another \"value\" that is messed up by quotation marks\", \"val3\": \"etc. etc.\"}' (length=191)

string '{"val1": "This is \"some value\" that is inside of the \"string\" and such", "val2": "And here is yet another \"value\" that is messed up by quotation marks", "val3": "etc. etc."}' (length=179)
```